# Number of conjugacy classes of finite reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{Z}$.  Let $c_{G(\mathbb{F}_q)}$ be the number of conjugacy classes of $G(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Question: Is it true that $c_{G(\mathbb{F}_q)}$ is a [quasi-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial) in $q$? I.e. is it true that there exists an integer $N$ (depending only on $G$) such that for every $i\in \{0,1,\dotsc,N-1\}$ there exists a polynomial $P_i$ such that $c_{G(\mathbb{F}_q)}=P_i(q)$ for all $q\equiv i \bmod N$?

If the answer is yes, then a type-independent explanation would be desirable. I'm mainly interested in the case $i=1$ but the general question seems worthwhile.

Frank Lübeck's tables at [Character Degrees and their Multiplicities for some Groups of Lie Type of Rank < 9](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EFrank.Luebeck/chev/DegMult/index.html) illustrate that the question has a positive answer for (simply connected form of) exceptional groups. For instance, for $G_2$, $E_6$ and $E_7$, the site states that $N=6$ and gives the explicit polynomials. We also have a lot of positive evidence for classical groups coming from explicit computations in [Macdonald - Numbers of conjugacy classes in some finite classical groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/numbers-of-conjugacy-classes-in-some-finite-classical-groups/98990E5FA1506E488ED8FEC336E46320) and [Wall - On the conjugacy classes in the unitary, symplectic, and orthogonal groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700027622) among others.

Comment: Since you want to study the dependence on $q$ don’t you want $G$ to be defined over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Corrected.Thanks.

Comment: even the case of tori would be a good starting point. Also "reductive over $\mathbf{Q}$" was more general: then counting is well-defined for large enough characteristic. For instance if one considers the $\mathbf{Z}$-group scheme  "$x^3=1$", it's reductive in characteristic $\neq 3$ but not char 3. Its number of $F_q$-points is $3$ if $3|q-1$ and $1$ if $3|q+1$.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the comment. Yes, reductive over Q is more general and we can consider that as well.

Comment: @YCor, how is reductivity defined for non-smooth group schemes?  (Or is the point that smoothness is built into the definition, so that a non-smooth group scheme is automatically non-reductive?)

Comment: For tori, this is the same as the number of elements. That is not quasi-polynomial for most non-split tori, as you can see by looking at the Weil restriction of $\mathbb G_m$ from a the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ of a number field $K$ to $\mathbb Z$. The $\mathbb F_p$-points will be the multiplicative group of $\mathcal O_K/p$, so the splitting type will not just depend on the congruence class of $p$ unless $K$ is an abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$. So maybe you want to restrict to split groups?

Comment: @LSpice There are smooth examples of similar phenomena. For example, these Weil restrictions are smooth but not reductive at the ramified primes.

Comment: @LSpice this sounds reasonable (to assume smoothness in the definition) but I'm not sure what the established terminology is.

Comment: @WillSawin As you note, for non-split groups there are some obstructions. We can try throwing away some primes (including ramified primes).

Comment: Is there anything like rational canonical form for reductive groups other than type A? Because that's how I would think about the $GL_n$ case.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, I think that the general way to think of (primary) rational canonical form is essentially the classification of semisimples (by separable polynomials) + classification of rational nilpotent orbits in semisimple centralisers (by writing as a product of $\operatorname R_{E/F}\operatorname{GL}_n$'s and partitioning $n$).

Comment: @LSpice I think I want actual rational canonical form, not the primary variant. Here is an example in $GL_4$. Conjugacy classes of semisimple elements correspond to points of $(T/W)(\mathbb{F}_p)$. We can stratify this quotient according to the conjugacy class of the stabilizer in $W$; let's look at points which have $S_2 \times S_2$ stabilizer. This means that their characteristic polynomial is of the form $f(x)^2$ for a separable quadratic $f$. Using rational canonical form, we see that the classes are indexed by sequences of the forms $(f(x)^2)$, $(f(x), f(x))$ and $((x-a)^2(x-b), (x-b))$.

Comment: It is easy to see that each of the above cases has polynomial point count. By contrast, if we use primary rational canonical form, we have to keep track of whether or not $f(x)$ factors. If $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$, then I get that there are $4$ conjugacy classes of unipotent commuting with the semisimple element; if $f(x)$ is irreducible, then there are only $2$. It seems to me (but maybe I am wrong) that this is going to get hard to deal with as the complexity increases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assume that $G$ is adjoint split over $\mathbb F_q$. Let $G^*$ be the (Langlands) dual group; it is also split over $\mathbb F_q$. For each semisimple $s \in G^*( \mathbb F_q)$ let $N_s$ be the number of unipotent representations
of the centralizer $Z_{G^*}(s)(\mathbb F_q)$. The number of conjugacy classes in $G(\mathbb F_q)$ is equal to the number of irreducible characters of $G(\mathbb F_q)$ and this equals (by my 1984 classification) the sum $\sum_s N_s$ where $s$ runs over the $G^*(\mathbb F_q)$-conjugacy classes of semisimple elements in $G^*(\mathbb F_q)$. Since the $N_s$ are very well behaved (much better behaved that number of unipotent classes) this reduces the problem to a problem of counting semisimple classes in $G^*(\mathbb F_q)$ with centralizer of fixed type. From this the desired result follows.

The main point is that the number of unipotent classes in $G(\mathbb F_q)$ behaves differently in small characteristic while the number of uniptent representations of a reductive group over $\mathbb F_q$ is independent of characteristic. This makes it easier to count irreducible representations than conjugacy classes.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Prof. Lusztig!

Comment: I copied the text of the second answer into this one.